# How to solve error Undefined index in php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending arrays from View to Controller using Post Method. This is my code.

Controller:      `Session::put('isCheck', $isCheck);`

this is how i am assigning value to isChecked array.

```
   var isChecked = [
    <?php
    $isCheck = "";
    if (Session::has('isCheck')) {
        $isCheck = Session::get('isCheck');
    }
    foreach ($isCheck as $isCheck) {
        $status = $isCheck;
        ?>
        <?php echo $status; ?>,
    <?php } ?>
   ];
```

View:

```
  $("#target").click(function () {
                    var postTo = '<?php echo action('sample@postView'); ?>';
                    var data = {
                        isChecked: isChecked,
                        duplicateIsChecked: duplicateIsChecked
                    };
                    jQuery.post(postTo, data,
                            function (data) {
                                alert(data);

                            });
                });
```

isChecked and DuplicateIsChecked are my 2arrays.

In controller I am writing this code:

```
 $duplicateIsChecked = $_POST['duplicateIsChecked'];
 $isCheck = $_POST['isChecked'];
```

But i am getting Undefined index duplicateIsChecked error. Help me

Comment: I didn't get it. `isChecked` and `duplicateIsChecked` are javascript variables right ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the header of your Ajax call to make sure its sending any data? In the code you posted, you're assigning variables to the two values in data but you didn't show where you are declaring those variable values.

Comment: <?php
$isCheck = "";
if (Session::has('isCheck')) {
    $isCheck = Session::get('isCheck');
}
foreach ($isCheck as $isCheck) {
    $status = $isCheck;
    ?>
    <?php echo $status; ?>,
<?php } ?>
                    ];

Comment: Is this in the page where you're sending the Ajax call or receiving it?

Comment: i am sending hard code array from controller to view and in the view am taking that array in global array variable using above code so that i can use that array in whole view and after using that array i am again sending updated array to controller using POST method.

Comment: You named your variable IsChecked (With a capital I) but in your ajax data you refer to isChecked (with a lower-case i). Javascript is case sensitive so that might be the issue.

Comment: no no while posting que by mistaken i have written that capital I.in code i have used isChecked only.

Comment: In the actual header of the Ajax call what post data is it showing as being passed in the request.

Comment: i am not getting what u r trying to assk?

Comment: If you use something like Chrome's Developer Tools you can look at your network requests as well as things like the header information (which will hold the data you actually passed in the ajax call).

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass a javascript array to php like that, you have to convert the array into JSON and send it.

so it should be

```
   var data = JSON.stringify({
                        isChecked: isChecked,
                        duplicateIsChecked: duplicateIsChecked
                    });
```

To get the JSON payload in controller, you can use

```
$payload = Input::json()->all();
```

then to access the attribute, you can reference it as 
`$payload['duplicateIsChecked']` & `$payload['isChecked']`

Comment: Did you try printing $payload, what is it giving ? Is your URL correct ?

Comment: yes i tried printing $payload['isChecked']. but it is saying undefined index isChecked.

Comment: Can you please post your JS AJAX call and controller code ?

Comment: from controller i am creating Session for isChecked and in View i am using GET session method and assigning that array to JS variable isChecked

Comment: Try logging your JS array using console.log(JS_ARRAY) before sending in AJAX call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74038/discussion-between-sameer-and-parag-bhingre).

Comment: @ParagBhingre Did you get the solution to the problem ?